# SwiftUI App Lifecycle, presentingViewController for GoogleSignIn

Tags: swiftui, google-signin

I want to integrate GoogleSignIn as a part of an iOS app with SwiftUI Lifecycle. Since there is no UIViewController, AppDelegate or SceneDelegate in SwiftUI Lifecycle app, how to provide one to GoogleSignIn sdk to present its view.

```swift
GIDSignIn.sharedInstance()?.presentingViewController = ?
```

Comment: Integrate it in your custom view controller and integrate your entire controller in SwiftUI via UIViewControllerRepresentable wrapper.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@asperi's solution worked perfectly, feel silly for not thinking it myself actually.

Just wrap all your UIKit needs in a new UIViewControllerRepresentable and access that via SwiftUI.